# Cannot upload in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I preface with this question: Are there any step-by-step directions on how to upload an an-app purchase from XCODE? (Hint: Apple's documentation does not do 
this.)

I have also tried to upload using ARCHIVE from XCODE. If select , I get a dialog with "Signing Identity: Not Signed". I can then click  on the dialog box which gives the same dialog again with the message

```
      Archive submission failed due to the issues listed below.

      Unable to validate your application.
      The package does not contain an info.plist
```

I have seen questions here describing this error; no of which have an accepted answer.

I have seen the suggestion to export instead. I have tried exporting the package then use application loader. When I do that, after clicking , I get this error: "The Archive for In-App purchase "PURCHASENAME" is invalid. The 'IAPPProductIdentifier' in the ContentInfo.plist  must match the In-App purchase ID."

This error occurs when I use the default value with "companyID.$()" (with the project name "PURCHASENAME". I have tried changing that to "companyid.PURCHASENAME" but that gives the same error. So does using "PURCHASENAME". (It would be great if there were documentation specifying EXACTLY what values need to go into the field). PURCHASENAME matches the name of the in-app purchase I created on iTunes connect. It also matched EXACTLY the purchase name as displayed by Application Load.

What do I have to do to upload an in-app purchase?